# Negating conditions in Watson Conversation

Tags: json, watson-conversation, watson

I'm using Watson conversation to help run a virtual support system and am trying to figure out how to play with conditions a bit more. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to negate conditions or to specify a condition not found.

For example, I have an entity @sports with the sub-entities @sports:mlb, @sports:nba, @sports:nhl, and @sports:nfl. I'm looking for a way to specify recognizing any of these *except* nba (I know I could just specify the other three, but I have other similar needs where that is less feasible).

Ideally, it would be as easy as:
**If bot recognizes: 

@sports AND !@sports:nba** (sports and not nba)
but that doesn't seem to work.

Is this doable? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello @CStephens what have you tried so far? Also welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@sports AND !@sports:nba
```

What could be causing it to fail is that you didn't select **"Create New Condition"** on the second part.

### Entity for sports.

[image]

### Dialog Nodes

[image]

### Dialog Node with condition.

(Remember, create new condition)
[image]

### Results

[image]

---

Outside of this, a common mistake is to forget to add `#` or `@`.

Get into the habit of naming your intents `#ALL_IN_CAPITALS` and your entity names in `@CamelCase`.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question for anyone else looking for this answer:

An exclamation point before the entity DOES, in fact, work to negate the response.

I'm not sure why it wasn't earlier; likely a misrecognized entity.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Official documentation, Watson uses the following example to Accessing entities with one negative example:

```
@year != 2016
```

In this case, your example will be:

```
@sports != 'nba'
```

- See the official [Reference](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-entities).